# Watching the output of a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, watch, heredoc

I'm trying to use `watch` to look at the output of a shell script, executing `/bin/bash` and holding the script itself in a heredoc.

The booger is only executing once though. It gives the correct output, then watch refreshes and the screen goes blank. Upon exiting `watch` there are no errors listed.

I can't figure out where the issue is since it's getting difficult to debug with `watch` > `bash` > `heredoc` > `ugly code`.

The good news is that `ugly code` in the heredoc works fine.

```
function show_users { 

    [[ -z $1 ]] && watchtime=1 || watchtime=$1
    [[ -z $2 ]] && export userToShow="mydefaultuser" || export userToShow=$2

    echo "Setting up watch for user ${userToShow}"

    watch -n $watchtime --no-title /bin/bash <<-'EOF'
        #Show finger results of requested user
        finger ${userToShow}

        #show list of users su'd into requested user
        echo "************************************************************************************"
        echo "users logged in as ${userToShow}"

        #get the parent PIDS of any process belonging to requested user
        #into a list that can be read by grep
        parentPIDs=$(ps -ef | grep "su - ${userToShow}" | grep -v 'grep\|finger' | awk 'NR>1{printf " %s \\|",parentpid}{parentpid=$3}END{printf " %s\n", parentpid}')

        #get usersnames associated to those parent PIDS
        parentUsers=$(ps -ef | grep "${parentPIDs}" | grep -v "grep\|${userToShow}" | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq)

        #finger each of these users and get their full name
        while IFS= read -r line ; do
            printf "%s: " $line
            parentName=$(finger $line | awk -F":" 'NR==1{print $3}')
            echo $parentName
        done <<< "${parentUsers}"

        #show tree for all proceses being run by requested user up to root.
        echo "************************************************************************************"
        ps -ef --forest | egrep -e "sshd:|-ksh|$userToShow" | grep -v grep | awk 'root==1{print ""} NR>1{print line} {line=$0;root=($1=="root") ? 1 : 0}'
    EOF
}
```

called like:

```
show_users 2 "username"
```

Comment: The basic issue is that the heredoc is attached to the stdin of watch which is executed only once. The first `bash` inherits stdin and consumes all of the here doc, when the next bash is invoked, there is nothing left in stdin. (Just a comment as I don't have a good solution.)

Comment: @CharlesBailey I was thinking something like that was the case. Perhaps if I `cat` the heredoc into a variable and then `bash -c` the variable in the `watch`... I'll keep tinkering.

Comment: The M in MCVE is "Minimal". You can replace this entire post with `watch /bin/bash << 'EOF'` `date` `EOF`

Comment: Define a function and `export -f` it. Then you can simply `watch bash -c yourfunc`

Comment: The `ps` parsing is a common and widespread antipattern. If you're running Awk anyway, you can easily factor the `grep` into the Awk script, too. See [useless use of `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: @thatotherguy I agree, and I have done that as a test. The complexities of `ugly code` though introduce other issues for recommended solutions, such as cat'ing the heredoc into a variable and `bash -c` the variable.

Comment: @triplee, the anti-pattern is a good point. I wrote a lot of this years ago. It's just now that I am trying to shoe horn it into `watch`.

Comment: @triplee Your suggestion to stick `ugly code` in a function and export did the trick. Thank you SO much. I can concentrate on de-uglying this thing now.

Comment: @tripleee: Can you add points on more how adding the function did the trick here?

Comment: It's not altogether different from saving it to a file in your `PATH` and making it executable. I posted a brief answer; if you want more details, please comment on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the code in a function. With `export -f func` you make the function definition available to subprocesses of the current script, so that you can then say

```
watch bash -c func
```

In OP's example:

```
# don't use bash-only (IMHO ugly) function syntax
get_user_info () {
    local userToShow=$1

    # No need for braces around variable names unless disambiguation is required
    finger "$userToShow"

    echo "lots of ugly asterisks"
    echo "users logged in as ${userToShow}"

    # avoid grep | grep | awk
    # field specifier can probasbly be made more strict
    # (match only $2 instead of $0)?
    parentPIDs=$(ps -ef |
        awk -v user="$userToShow" 'NR>1 && ($0 ~ "su - " user) {
                printf " %s \\|",parentpid}
            {parentpid=$3}
            END{printf " %s\n", parentpid}')

    # Would be better if parentPIDs was a proper regex
    # Assumes you are looking for the PPID in column 3
    parentUsers=$(ps -ef |
        awk -v pids="$parentPIDs" 'parentPIDs ~$3 {print $1}' |
        # prefer sort -u over sort | uniq
        sort -u)

    while IFS= read -r line ; do
        printf "%s: " "$line"
        # No need to capture output just to echo it
        finger "$line" | awk -F":" 'NR==1{print $3}'
    done <<< "${parentUsers}"

    echo "Another ugly lot of asterisks"
    # Again, the regex can probably be applied to just one field
    ps -ef --forest |
        awk -v re="sshd:|-ksh|$userToShow"  '$0 !~ re { next }
            root==1{print ""}
            NR>1{print line}
            {line=$0;root=($1=="root" || $3==1) ? 1 : 0}'
}

export -f get_user_info

show_users () {
     # Avoid complex [[ -z ... ]]; use defaults with ${var-"value if unset"}
     # Mark these as local to avoid polluting global namespace
     local watchtime={$1-1}
     local userToShow=${2-mydefaultuser}
     # no need to export these variables

     echo "$mycommand"
     echo "Setting up watch for user ${userToShow}"

     watch -n $watchtime --no-title bash -c get_user_info "$userToShow"
}
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind I edited to add the solution based on my answer to your very correct answer. Thanks again for the guidance! I was pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: Thank you SO much. That is really nice to see cleaned up! Though I think you should embrace the ugly asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

`watch` repeatedly runs a specified command with its arguments.
The heredoc, and more generally the effect of redirect operators are *not* part of the command.
So `watch` cannot re-generate the heredoc.
And once the heredoc is consumed by the first run of `bash`,
well, there will be nothing left for the second.

There's a dirty hack you could try at the bottom of this answer.
But my recommended solution is to save the content of the `heredoc` in a temporary file.
That's reasonably simple to do and robust.

Save the file in a temporary file, created by `mktemp`.
Setup a `trap` to catch the interrupt and perhaps other signals to make sure the temporary file gets cleaned up.
Run `watch bash "$tmpfile"`.
This is simple and will work.

#### Dirty "solution" with (severe) caveats, don't do this!

You could put a script in a variable and then run with `watch` like this:

```
watch "bash -c '$var'"
```

Or like this:

```
watch "bash -c \"$var\""
```

But the severe caveat is that the first version will break if `var` contains `'`, and the second version will break if `var` contains `"`.
So these would work with only the most basic kind of scripts,
and certainly not the one in your example.

This is clearly not an option, I just added here for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Your dirty variable workaround is good, but obviously the issue is that I have both quotes hanging out, even nested, in the script. Also at this point I might as well just shove the whole script into watch directly and deal with the same quote-escaping nightmare.

Comment: @JNevill why not save the script to a file?

Comment: I can see how having the full solution split across two scripts would be cumbersome. Keeping everything in a single file removes a number of problems with distribution logistics (can't save the script in `/tmp` if it's mounted with `noexec`, avoid the I/O overhead and traps for dealing with temporary files, etc).